# How to get photo with caption from user with telebot

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to get a photo with a caption on my Telegram bot with python.

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
```

I want to do thing like this to get photo with caption.

Answer (score 1):

To do this,

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['photo'])
def some_function(message):
    print(message.caption) # This will be your caption.
```

**Note**: You can't use `message.caption` everywhere because it will not be available for text message